# GitHub помощь в понимании работы в команде

Tags: github

С Гитом раньше в соло, и траблов не возникало никогда. Теперь работаю в команде с другом. Но мой мозг не может понять что за чем надо делать, и как избежать проблем в мерж веток на всякий случай.

Мое понимание такого, если я не прав, напишите последовательность что за чем и как надо делать поочереди:
Допустим, я залил удаленный реп, со стартовыми файлами, теперь, мне я так понимаю, надо у себя локально сделать свою ветку, например, "Дмитрий", и работать в ней, вечером к примеру закомитить и запушить на Гит, но как правильно мне запушить, и как мне создать на гите ту ветку на которой я работаю. Друг делает аналогично. А утром мы просто вызываем гит баш, и пуллом забираем с репа данные, перед этим мержим их в мастер ветку.

Кто-нибудь, обьясните по шагам, буду признателен.

Comment: аминь, гит по началу ужасает

Comment: Такой зашквар, мне джава скрипт было проще понять(((

Comment: Кратко: ветки — не про людей, а про задачи. Для каждой задачи — новая ветка из ветки `master`. Запушили ветку — открывайте пуллреквест.  В нём проверяйте друг друга — есть ли ошибки, всё ли понятно. Всё хорошо — принимайте пуллреквест.